# Как машинно перемножить два двоичных числа?

Tags: алгоритм

Положительных трехразрядных. 
 Нужен алгоритм.

Comment: машинно или алгоритм? определитесь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

элементарно - столбиком

Comment: тому кто заминусовал - молодое поколение видимо не умеет умножать столбиком?

Comment: [Здесь](http://basicschool.narod.ru/index.html?page=info_bases_07)

Концептуально ничем не отличается от обычного умножения.

Answer (score 1):

Положительные трёхразрядные двоичные числа (двоичные триады) - это цифры в двоично-восьмеричной системе счисления. Восьмеричная таблица умножения содержит  64 произведения.

Если таблицу умножения 0*0, 0*1, ... 0*7, 1*0, 1*0, ..., 7*7 представить как одномерный массив на 64 значения, то в качестве индекса можно использовать конкатенацию триад сомножителей.